# Override class property before parent constructor is called

Tags: kotlin

I have multiple classes that extend another class. Some of these classes have a different default context then the base class. In other programming languages this is no problem but in Java/Kotlin this seems to be impossible as properties are apparently not initialised first but after the constructor.

It will probably be easier with an example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var a = ClassA("ipsum")
}

abstract class Base(var word: String) {
    open var defaultPrefix: String = "lorem ".also(::println)

    init {
        println("init Base")
        word = defaultPrefix + word
        println("final value of word is '$word'")
    }
}

class ClassA(word: String) : Base(word) {
    override var defaultPrefix: String = "foobar ".also(::println)
}

class ClassB(word: String) : Base(word) {
    // methods will differ but it will have the same defaultContext as Base
}
```

Unfortunately this code does not work as `defaultPrefix` is `null`.
Here is the output:

```
lorem 
init Base
final value of word is 'nullipsum'
foobar
```

So apparently `init` of the `Base` class is called before the property is initialised.
Is there any way how I can initialise the property before init is called so that `word` would be `foobar ipsum` in my example?

Comment: Calling a local open function or property from a constructor is a big anti pattern and source of bugs in Java and Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should **NOT** happen. A `String` should be a non-nullable type no matter what the context. Please file a bug at [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT). There is a [similar bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43019/False-positive-Condition-is-always-true-when-property-is-null-and-referencable-during-super-constructor-before-it-is-initialized) that also notes that non-nullable variables are being set to null.

Anyway, this is a solution that you can use:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var a = ClassA("ipsum")
}

abstract class Base(var word: String) {
    open val defaultPrefix: String
        get() = "lorem ".also(::println)

    init {
        println("init Base")
        word = defaultPrefix + word
        println("final value of word is '$word'")
    }
}

class ClassA(word: String) : Base(word) {
    override val defaultPrefix: String
        get() = "foobar ".also(::println)
}

class ClassB(word: String) : Base(word) {
    // methods will differ but it will have the same defaultContext as Base
}
```

Comment: It's not a bug. This specific corner case is mentioned on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-nullable-types (Quote: "A superclass constructor calls an open member whose implementation in the derived class uses an uninitialized state.") Still, this is the correct answer: Converting the backed property to a getter ensures that the data is available on-demand.

Comment: This works like a charm and fixes my use case. It is quite unfortunate that Java seems to be the only language that I have worked with so far that needs silly workarounds like that. But as long as it works somehow I'm fine. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that directly.  **A base class is always constructed before its subclass.**  Every constructor implicitly or explicitly calls its superclass constructor as its first action<sup>*</sup>; then it runs any initialiser and initialiser blocks (in textual order); then the rest of its constructor.

(This isn't only a Kotlin restriction; it's also fundamental to Java.)

The reasoning behind it is that a subclass is likely to depend in many ways, explicitly or implicitly, upon its superclass, and so **a superclass must be fully functioning by the time anything in the subclass runs** — fully initialised and with all its invariants in place.

Note that although **a constructor or initialiser can call overridable methods/properties**, this is dangerous and not recommended.  For complete safety, the compiler would prevent it — but it's very hard to ensure (as the calls could be indirect); and it would also make some types of initialisation much harder to write.  And so the language allows it as a concession.

One side-effect of this is that it's possible to see properties before they've been initialised, when they still hold the JVM default (0 for numeric types, false for booleans, and null for references), even if those wouldn't be valid values<sup>**</sup>.

If you *do* choose to access an overridable method/property despite this, **the IDE gives you a warning**: in this case, IDEA shows `Accessing non-final property defaultPrefix in constructor`, which warns you that you could be causing exactly this type of problem.  Take heed of the warning!

<sup>*</sup> There is a slight exception to this: if the superclass constructor takes one or more parameters, it can be called with expressions that need to be evaluated, e.g.:

```
class Child(word: String): Parent("$word in child")
```

Of course, this simple string template is perfectly safe; and I don't *think* it's possible to access superclass methods or properties in this way (because there's not yet a ‘this’ to call them on).  But this may let you **refactor your code to do what you want in a slightly different way**, such as:

```
abstract class Base(var word: String, val prefix: String = defaultPrefix) {
    companion object {
        const val defaultPrefix = "lorem"
    }

    init {
        println("init Base")
        word = "$prefix $word"
        println("final value of word is '$word'")
    }
}

class ClassA(word: String) : Base(word, defaultPrefix + " foobar")
```

Here the prefix is passed *into* the superclass, so it's always calculated first and well-defined.  — Of course, this example may not meet your needs, but I hope it illustrates the sort of approach you might take.

<sup>(** This is mentioned in the [Kotlin language documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-nullable-types) as one of the very few possible causes of a NullPointerException.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

##### Parent objects are always constructed first

No, there is no realistic way of initialising an inherited property in the child class before it is accessed in the parent constructor. As [@gidds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10134209/gidds) says in [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531408/override-class-property-before-parent-constructor-is-called#answer-77531882), it's a fundamental aspect of Kotlin and Java that parent objects are constructed first.

##### The underlying problem

It seems that your problem is that you:

- Want some initialisation code to run in the parent, since it is to apply to all children, but
- Want that code to depend on a value set in the child.

##### Lazy properties

This problem is solved by deferring running the initialisation code until the parent is initialised*, which can most easily be done in Kotlin by placing the relevant parent code in a [lazy property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#lazy-properties).

Here I've rewritten the example with `word` initialised lazily:

```
fun main() {
    var a = ClassA("ipsum")
    var b = ClassB("ipsum")
    println("final value of word is in A is '${a.word}'")
    println("final value of word is in B is '${b.word}'")
}

abstract class Base(wordInit: String) {
    open var defaultPrefix: String = "lorem "
    
    val word: String by lazy { defaultPrefix + wordInit }
}

class ClassA(word: String) : Base(word) {
    override var defaultPrefix: String = "foobar "
}

class ClassB(word: String) : Base(word) {
    // methods will differ but it will have the same defaultPrefix as Base
}
```

Output (see [playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)):

```
final value of word is in A is 'foobar ipsum'
final value of word is in B is 'lorem ipsum'
```

---

*This would not work if the code you wanted to run in a parent constructor had side effects, such as printing an output to the console (as used in your example). This is because by doing this we are delaying the running of the code to a later time and possibly reordering program execution. However I would argue running code with side effects in a constructor is not good practice since a constructor is for building an object and not doing anything else. Thus this should not be a problem in practice.

If you want to run code with side effects when constructing an object, you can use a factory or factory method.